# C# Components programming?

Tags: c#, components

Can anyone explain me briefly what exactly is **component programming in .NET** and why would I use it ?

I don't understand if it's an alternative to Object Oriented Programming or what.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would point out this excellent article from MSDN

> [Class vs. Component vs. Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1dk63b.aspx)

to let you evaluate what is what and when to use what :)